# Shopify - Rewrite the Add to cart button code to send custom AJAX request that includes custom products

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, liquid

I have created a custom ["Related products"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VtI1.png) section on the product page, that allows users to select extra products.

I have written jQuery script that takes the two selected items and the main item on which product page you are on and add them to cart:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function() {
  var items = [];
  var checkboxes = ['product-a', 'product-b'];
  var selected_variation = $('#product_variants').val();

  items.push({ quantity: parseInt($('input.quantity__input').val()), id: '' + {{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }} });

  document.getElementById('product-b').value = selected_variation;
  for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if($('#' + checkboxes[i]).is(':checked')) {
      items.push({ quantity: 1, id: $('#' + checkboxes[i]).val() });
    }
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    data: { items: items },
    success: function(data) {
      console.info('success',data);
    },
  dataType: 'application/json'
  });
  });
});
```

I was planning to just remove the `type="submit"` from the original Add to cart button code and give it the class .btn, all of this works, however what I was not planning for is that now if there is an error for example when you try to add more items to card then there are available, it won't show up.

I would like to rewrite the original button with the change of the data it sends, but to keep rest of the code original.

I am using the Dawn theme from shopify.

Any ideas how should I proceed to solve this? I am quit new to Shopify, so sorry if I have made some stupid coding error or used bad practices.

I have checked the [Shopify AJAX API](https://shopify.dev/api/ajax) page and their documentation for the theme, but can't find my solution there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit inventory for a variant to the amount available or less, you have to do some work. First off, you know the product and its variant ID. You can use that to ask Shopify how much inventory is currently available, or, even easier, when you render the product in the first place using Liquid, you can also render out the inventory quantity.

With that number, you can inform the customer they cannot have 8 if there are only 7 in inventory. Has nothing to do with Shopify Ajax API calls.

It can get a little gnarly adding this level of control but in the end, Shopify Ajax calls are pretty simple, you get back a 200 OK or you don't. How you proceed with this is up to you. It sounds like you have the basics in place nicely, so carry on!